# Why isn't "if" an expression in C

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-construction

What is the reason for 'if' statements in C not to be expressions? Why was the ternary operator added to C instead of 'if' expressions?

Are there technical reasons or is it just a historical decision?

Ed.: to make things more clear, I've imagined an 'if' expression like this: if its result is not used, it may behave just like a statement, but if something requires the result, it must have the `else` branch of the same return type.

Now I see that the result is ambiguous: indeed, it's a weird hybrid of expression and statement, so the clear separation is better.

Comment: What would an `if` expression evaluate to?

Comment: aren't if expressions ternary operator in c? i think they are the same thing

Comment: @Jon I do can write some arithmetical expression in C like a statement, why not?

Comment: Because if `if` was an expression, each branch would have been able to be evaluated to a value of the same type. Which is a pain. Try to use the terneary expression instead of `if` while you program, and you'll see.

Comment: @EarlGray: Did you answer my question with that? Try answering it and see a) how difficult it is to come up with an answer that can endure criticism, b) how (not) useful the feature would be, given the restrictions that an ironclad answer will need to impose.

Comment: Are you in effect asking, "why did C use the `? :` syntax for conditional expressions, instead of something involving the keyword `if`"? The straight answer to your question is that `if` is not an expression because `if` is the syntax for conditional statements, whereas `?:` is the syntax for conditional expressions. The two have different advantages and disadvantages, so both are useful.

Comment: @SteveJessop Rather no. Why C has not been more functional from the start? Was it ignorance or inertia? Does the statements model fits its tasks better, than why? 

I think there was some way of embedding expressional 'if' into the language, if not, why?

Comment: @EarlGray what's the difference between expressional if and ternary operator, other than the symbols (`if` and `?:`)?

Comment: @EarlGray: So what's the specific difference between the conditional expressions C actually has, compared with the conditional expressions that you're saying it could have? Without knowing what you're proposing I can't venture an opinion why it wasn't the natural thing for C to have done. If the debate broadens to "why does C have statements at all", or "why is it an imperative language" then I think you lose suitable focus for SO.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, it looks like this question boils down to "why statements are not expressions and why they're useful in C", which is obvious for me. But still, why 'if' does not return anything (even `void`)?

Comment: i still don't get what's the essential difference between `int x = a < b ? 3 : 5`; and let's say if returned a value, with a hypothethical syntax `int x = if (a < b) return 3 else return 5;` @EarlGray can you tell me what's the difference?

Comment: @EarlGray: well, statements in general don't return anything because the grammar doesn't let you use them in contexts that require a value (or non-value in the case of `void`). The reason for that, is to reduce the "burden" on the language design to always supply a value. If the specific problem you face is that you're trying to write something in part 3 of a `for` loop that can't be written as an expression then we've all been there, but you just have to suck it up and write another function ;-)

Comment: @AliVeli Just that: why this syntax is "hypothetical", not an actual one.

Comment: @EarlGray: That part of the question *is* what I asked, isn't it, "why doesn't the ternary operator syntax involve the keyword `if`"? To which I speculate (a) that it was introduced before there were *any* keyword operators in C (`sizeof` initially being a macro), and/or (b) because Ritchie or someone else thought that it would appear ambiguous even if it wasn't formally so. The multiple and confusing meanings of `static` also came later ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop This sounds the most convincing of the answers. That's the C, not a functional language and I have to put up with the fact that some things must be statements. I've just tried to dig into historical roots, to find a possible logical reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say because C is an imperative language, modeling machines, not maths, where all functions have a value.

An if-expression needs a mandatory else-expression (or a mandatory exception-throw), which does not fit nicely in a performance- and machine-oriented programming language in which you only pay for what you use.

---

(sidenote)
The standard could state that if the if-expression is not on the right hand side of an assignment, that the else part becomes optional. That, however, would make the C grammar more complex.

A second restriction: Within an expression, you can only use other expressions. You can't for example:

```
int i = if (foo) { for (int x=4; x; --x) {}; 42 } else bar;
```

While in principle possible, I think that would take away some of C's beautiful, minimalistic grammar; you would have to extend the rules for trivial expressions vs. code blocks, you need to remember more context while parsing, and so on. (/sidenote)

---

The ternary operator in C++ (note: *C++*) does exactly that: Requiring an else-part because it is an expression or throwing an exception:

```
int foo = frob ? bar : throw "crap";
```

That thing is basically an if-else-*expression*; Python would be an example for a language that replaced `?:` with `if/else`:

```
foo = frob if bar else 42
```

What you describe is really two things: If-statements and if-expression. Both are in C; both have distinct features. And, somehow, you ask why not both *if-statements* **and** *if-expressions* are *expressions*.

Comment: voids are still valid expressions. The problem comes when you want to define a loop in it.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty possible to return void if nobody wants the result. And even more, it's possible to cast both results (of different types, maybe) to `void` if it is not used.

Comment: @LtWorf: I revised my answer and removed the void-argument after thinking about it. You can even return _void_ in C++-templates.

Comment: Sure you can, void is a type.

Comment: A nice point about modeling machines. "Mandatory" `else` can be eliminated: again, if nobody uses the result, it may be optional, so the performance argument does not work.

Comment: @LtWorf: ... depends on the context. In any case, you can't `return XXX`, with `XXX` being of type `void`, in non-template code in C++ (e.g. `void foo() {} void bar() { return foo(); }` is not valuid C++.

Comment: @EarlGray: Seems I overlooked your comment previously, sorry for that. Good point again, and thinking about it leads me to another revision of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the last edit is what I've asked about.

Answer (score 0):

An if is defined with something like that:

```
"if" <whitespace> "(" <whitespace> <expression> <whitespace> ")" <whitespace> <statement>
```

So it will accept a statement if the condition is met. If it was an expression it would need to return something, hence it would only be able to execute other expressions rather than general statements. In fact the ?: can only execute conditional expressions but not statements.

Comment: You don't need to mention whitespace everywhere. The lexer would detect and throw away the whitespace (comments included) before passing the tokens over to the parser. So what the parser sees actually (or in other words, the grammar it parses) has no whitespace.

Comment: It's a pseudo-grammar example...

Comment: Even more the reason for not writing the whitespace. All I'm saying is that it clutters what you are trying to say with unnecessary information.